# Custom Django User with Default values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 3.2 with Restframework.
I have created a custom user Model for my project and given default values in Models for some fields.

But the default values are not accepted when the POST request is made. Like for example, "date_joined" is left blank, then it has to be today's date, but while making request from postman, its taking it as mandatory field.
Is anything missing, while defining custom User?

Models.py

```
class MasterUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',max_length=255,unique=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
    membership_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    objects = MyUserManager()
```

serializer

```
class RegisterUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
...
...
    def save(self):
        
        timestamp = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
        account = MasterUser(
            email = self.validated_data['email'],
            firstname = self.validated_data['firstname'],
            lastname = self.validated_data['lastname'],
            is_member = self.validated_data['is_member'],
            date_joined = self.validated_data['date_joined'],
            membership_id = hashString(str(timestamp))
        )

        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password doesnt matches'})
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        return account
```

views.py

```
def registration_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        is_member = request.POST.get('is_member')
        timestamp = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data= request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():

            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = "Successfully registered new user!"
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['firstname'] = account.firstname
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: Try giving `blank = True` as an attribute in the models to the fields that are not necessary.
Example:
`date_joined = models.DateField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)`. Is `restframework` enforcing the same for `firstname` ?

Comment: It partially worked. I made ```blank=True``` in models then call the API, it throws ```key error``` for "date_joined". Then comment out "date_joined" in serializer and again call the API, it does create a User with today's date.

Comment: Right now ```firstname``` and ```lastname``` are excluded from restframework.

Comment: Yes,the key error is there because you are not sending any data with key in `date_joined` but you are trying to validate it.
I would suggest this date of join should not be validated rather you should let it take the automatic value.
Better to create another url to amend date if for some reason you want to do that.

Comment: That means, 2 url to to register the user? How to call 2nd url for just date or last_signed_in, category (this is supposed to be blank at first)? Like if the user wants to join on some future date that we are known about.

Comment: I meant if you don't supply and check for date it will take the default value so in future if admin need to change the date then you can do these changes with another api call to change date.
You can also get the list of keys from `request` `list(request.POST.items())` and get fields like this `Model._meta.get_fields()` and validate only the fields that are valid for that model and are also available in list of `request items`.

Comment: Sounds a good idea! Thanks a lot Dushyant